# Shell script execution on remote machine through Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins

I am running a Jenkins Job which transfers spring boot application .jar file on remote machine and then executes shell script on remote machine to execute jar file.

However I found , the moment Jenkins Job completes with shell script execution , it is killing the process under which jar file is executing.

Any help ..

Comment: background the shell script or the part that runs the jar with an `&`? or please post your Jenkinsfile if you've got one.

Comment: Let us say on remote server .. startapp.sh containing following nohup java -jar spring_boot_application.jar &  .. startapp.sh has been added in Jenkins post Build section . Jenkins properly calls this file , but the spring boot application process is killed the moment jenkins closes its ssh session